# Python Code Reviewer

Tags: code-golf, python

### Task

Your mission is to create a program that reviews Python code. The solution can be written in any language!

It must take input that contains python code. The program must add `# This is not pythonic!` before each block of non-whitespace lines.

### Input

- The data can be entered via stdin.
- The data will contain at least 3 lines with one blank one in between
  them.

**Minimum input example.**

```
print "Hello World!"

Print "Bye World!"
```

**Sample Input**

```
from os.path import abspath

lines = []
with open(__file__, 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        lines.append(line)

if lines is not None:

    newLines = []
    hasReviewedBlock = False

    for line in lines:
        if len(line) > 1: # \n
            if hasReviewedBlock == False:
                newLines.append("# This is not pythonic!\n")
                hasReviewedBlock = True
        else:
            hasReviewedBlock = False

        newLines.append(line)
    with open("d:/test.py", 'w') as f:
        for line in newLines:
            f.write(line);
```

### Output

Output has to be written to STDOUT or closest alternative.

### Sample Output

```
# This is not pythonic!
from os.path import abspath

# This is not pythonic!
lines = []
with open(__file__, 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        lines.append(line)

# This is not pythonic!
if lines is not None:

# This is not pythonic!
    newLines = []
    hasReviewedBlock = False

# This is not pythonic!
    for line in lines:
        if len(line) > 1: # \n
            if hasReviewedBlock == False:
                newLines.append("# This is not pythonic!\n")
                hasReviewedBlock = True
        else:
            hasReviewedBlock = False

# This is not pythonic!
        newLines.append(line)
    with open("d:/test.py", 'w') as f:
        for line in newLines:
            f.write(line);
```

### Scoring:

Lowest number of bytes wins. -5 bytes if your program can be used as valid input.

Comment: You haven't explained how you decide if code is pythonic or not.

Comment: All python code is not Pythonic. Edited my question.

Comment: So what you're saying is that python itself is not pythonic?

Comment: So, simply put, we have to insert "# this is not pythonic" before each block of non-whitespace  lines? We're all for a joke here, but please make your spec crystal clear.

Comment: Yes, sorry I am not sure how to make it more clear. I have not made a code golf question before.

Comment: I don't quite understand the bonus. What does "can be used as valid input" mean? I figure pretty much any program in any language can be used as an input. What makes it valid?

Comment: Couple more questions: Can the first line be empty? Can there be sequences of multiple empty lines?

Comment: @RetoKoradi You can only put a blank line at the second line of code when the minimum is a 3LOC input with a line in "*between*". In this case, the first line can never be empty.

Comment: Are functions allowed?

Comment: Functions are allowed, the first line can not be empty. Valid input is python code. So basically to get the bonus it has to be in python, and have 2 code blocks.

Comment: whitespace`\t`is`\t`EVIL!

Answer (score 4):

## awk, <strike>64 56</strike> 54 bytes

```
/^$/{i=0}/./{if(!i++)print"# This is not pythonic!"}1
```

**Test:**

```
echo '/^$/{i=0}/./{if(!i++)print"# This is not pythonic!"}1' > solution.awk
awk -f solution.awk < pyth.py
awk -f solution.awk < pyth.py
```

**Explanation:**

`/^$/` - matches empty line,

`/./` - matches non-empty line,

`1` - matches each line. No body is equivalent to `{print;}` - each line of input is printed.

Answer (score 3):

## Pyth, <s>39</s> <s>38</s> 37 bytes

```
tjbm|d+b"# This is not pythonic!"+k.z
```

[Live demo.](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=tjbm%7Cd%2Bb"%23+This+is+not+pythonic%21"%2Bk.z&input=from+os.path+import+abspath%0A%0Alines+%3D+%5B%5D%0Awith+open%28__file__%2C+%27r%27%29+as+f%3A%0A++++for+line+in+f%3A%0A++++++++lines.append%28line%29%0A%0Aif+lines+is+not+None%3A%0A%0A++++newLines+%3D+%5B%5D%0A++++hasReviewedBlock+%3D+False%0A%0A++++for+line+in+lines%3A%0A++++++++if+len%28line%29+>+1%3A+%23+%5Cn%0A++++++++++++if+hasReviewedBlock+%3D%3D+False%3A%0A++++++++++++++++newLines.append%28"%23+This+is+not+pythonic%21%5Cn"%29%0A++++++++++++++++hasReviewedBlock+%3D+True%0A++++++++else%3A%0A++++++++++++hasReviewedBlock+%3D+False%0A%0A++++++++newLines.append%28line%29%0A++++with+open%28"d%3A%2Ftest.py"%2C+%27w%27%29+as+f%3A%0A++++++++for+line+in+newLines%3A%0A++++++++++++f.write%28line%29%3B&debug=1)

### Explanation

```
tjbm|d+b"# This is not pythonic!"+k.z
                                 +k.z    Prepend the empty line to the string
   m                                     For each line
    |d                                   If it's non-empty, return the same line
      +b"# This is not pythonic!"        Else, return a line break followed by the required text
 jb                                      Join via line breaks
t                                        Remove the unneeded preceding line break
```

## 38-byte version

```
tjbm?dd+b"# This is not pythonic!"+k.z
```

## 39-byte version

```
jbtsm?dd,d"# This is not pythonic!"+k.z
```

<s>No doubt there's still golfing left to do.</s>

Answer (score 2):

### AutoIt - 139

```
$1='# This is not pythonic!'
ConsoleWrite($1&@CRLF&StringRegExpReplace(FileRead($CmdLine[1]),'(*BSR_ANYCRLF)(^\R|\R(?=\R))',"\0"&@CRLF&$1))
```

I'm assuming the first line cannot be empty as by your specification:

> The data will contain at least 3 lines with one blank one in between them.

This program is called like this:

```
compiled.exe pycode.py > output.txt
```

The RegEx can be optimized for sure. Works for `CRLF` only.

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 86 bytes - 5 = 81

```python
import re

print(re.sub(r"(^\n*|\n\n+)",r"\1# This is not pythonic\n",open(0).read()))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fVHNTsMwDL7nKUx2WANTYeJWBAcOnBAHtBuFKltdNaJzoiSjmsS7l6RbN0YnrFxi@/uxbba@1nTbdWpttPVgkTFjFfnEYuo2y8Ty5COny@@ccroSfGZ5Pp/AolYOwiPtwfQUapUTn2mDlNyI1KIsEyFE11VWr0G71Ehfw15ELl38MtYoQgf38PbOWhXqPbwoKtVgUcxgaqcCpIMqYxCi0hYiAhQNqRg9SSpNwJZJ/AjGVLVLDx5fNGHGeghh@3yUjZlaulf8Uthi@djo1WeoPMnGIRup9pxH5agSDPea8ADzDCaQ06G8bxnT7/mzk87f3oZp@PlNX4RVixH4zBgLu8FDH44k/x/8nKHdemPleC9eZtcenU/NloebtSc3@7vBgfDUSJW2Vnnc0d/9AA)

---

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 94 bytes - 5 = 89

```python
p=''

for c in open(0).read().splitlines():print("# This is not pythonic!\n"*(p==''!=c)+c);p=c
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fVG9TsMwEN79FNd0SAwogNhShYGBCTGgbhRFJrkoFqlt2YaoTx9sJ2koqXry4rv7fu5OHWwjxUPfqzyOCamlhhK4AKlQJHc01ciqhKZGtdy2XKBJaKY0FzaJ1rBtuAH3hLSgAhEvVzsRXSUqd3SrvKTXJd2ovOz7Wss9SJMqZhvgeyW1BfZp/JeQwAw5vH@Qjrt6UC@KmrdYFDcQ65gCM1BnBFx4kx7hfY4pH4EkZcphq8R/KCG8HtKTy1cpMCMBIrB7mWV9pmHmDX84dlg9tbL8cpVn1hokC9XAOSt7FWc4aMIj3Gewhp04lseWJf3In510/vU2TXNh13QBPjPGVn/jsQ8XkpcHP2doWK@vzPeKquzWorGpOkTuZt3Jzf5vcCI8NVKnneYWB/rNLw)

Comment: @ReinstateMonica your code adds a `#` before the first line

Comment: Whoops! [78](https://tio.run/##fVE9b4MwEN39K65kANSItunmKB06dKo6VNlChBw4hFWwLdstyq@nNgmhlLQnS9bdu3vvPtTRVlI8dl2zCVORigVsK27APSEtqB7l@U0qwrXSXNio2a3o/lYqFNF9nGhkReQ/VbMcHUhX@2UTx11XatmANIlitgLeKKktsIPxLiE1F2hgA7s9abnDe7osK3mNWbaEUIcxMAMlJeCslBp8BXAxhLz1JAlTrraIvBMTwstTeBjgTQqkpC8R2L6Osj5SMfOOXxxbLJ5rmX845IXVBslMtecclb2Ka7jXhCd4oLCAVFzgc8qc/sxPJ5k/exumCf48QxDPiq@MsdWfeMnDmeT/g19r6LRej4z3Cgp6Z9HYRB0Dd7N2crPfGxwIp42USau5xRP9@hs "Python 3 – Try It Online"), my bad

Answer (score 2):

## [Wren](https://github.com/munificent/wren), 73-5 = 68 bytes

Luckily enough, Wren has an automatic WYSIWYG that gains the bonus.

```
Fn.new{|i|("

"+i).split("

").join("

# This is not pythonic!
")[2..-1]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Ky9KzftfllikkFaal6xgq/DfLU8vL7W8uiazRkOJi0tJO1NTr7ggJ7MEzNPUy8rPzAMxlRVCMjKLFYAoL79EoaCyJCM/LzNZEagk2khPT9cwtvZ/cGVxSWquXnlRZkmqBsh4veTEnBwNLiUkK2KARsUgWQLhQ62JwWNPDMIiJU3N/wA)

### Explanation

````
Fn.new{|i|    // In this case we define a new
              // anonymous function with the operand i
          ("

"+i)          // We prepend the input with 2 newlines
    .split("

")            // Split the input by newlines,
              // including the preceding newlines
              // that we first prepended
  .join("

# This is not pythonic!
")            // Join the input with 2 newlines
              // , the comment, and another trailing newline
  [2..-1]}    // Slice the input so that the preceding
              // 2 newlines are not present in the final output
```
````

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 40 - 5 = 35 bytes

```perl6
{S:g/^|"

"<(/# This is not pythonic!
/}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fVG9TsMwEN79FEcq0URCiVgYUmBgYEIM0I1CZNozsUhsy3aJIuDZg500TUMKJy@@u@/n7hTq4qIpazhlcAXN52P6lrx8BYQEl2Eyg2XODbgnpAVV21wKvj4hyXdjaA0MTLHVatEwLUuQJlbU5sBLJbUF@mr8l5CCCzSO@@mZVNzVpUIRZhnjBWbZGcz1PAJqgKUEXDCpwSOAiz7loyWJqXLYTeg/ESGcdene370UmJIWIrC6G2R9JqfmAT84Vri5KeT63VVuaWGQTFRbzkHZqzjDrSZcw3kKM1iJfXnXMqXf8aejzkNv/TTBH1teiSCagI@MsdRb3PfhRPL/wY8Z6tbrK8O9gk2aWDQ2VnXgblaNbvZ7gz3h2AiLK80tdvSLHw)

The bonus is rather weird, but it didn't cost me any bytes to add.

#### Explanation

```perl6
{S:g/        /   /}  # Substitute all instances of
     ^                 # The start of the string
      |"  "            # or two newlines
           <(          # But don't actually replace, just append
              ...    # With the given string
```

Answer (score 1):

## CJam, 41 bytes

```
"# This is not pythonic!":TNqN/{_{T}|}%N*
```

[Try it online](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=%22%23%20This%20is%20not%20pythonic!%22%3ATNqN%2F%7B_%7BT%7D%7C%7D%25N*&input=from%20os.path%20import%20abspath%0A%0Alines%20%3D%20%5B%5D%0Awith%20open(__file__%2C%20'r')%20as%20f%3A%0A%20%20%20%20for%20line%20in%20f%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20lines.append(line)%0A%0Aif%20lines%20is%20not%20None%3A%0A%0A%20%20%20%20newLines%20%3D%20%5B%5D%0A%20%20%20%20hasReviewedBlock%20%3D%20False%0A%0A%20%20%20%20for%20line%20in%20lines%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20len(line)%20%3E%201%3A%20%23%20%5Cn%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20hasReviewedBlock%20%3D%3D%20False%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20newLines.append(%22%23%20This%20is%20not%20pythonic!%5Cn%22)%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20hasReviewedBlock%20%3D%20True%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20else%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20hasReviewedBlock%20%3D%20False%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20newLines.append(line)%0A%20%20%20%20with%20open(%22d%3A%2Ftest.py%22%2C%20'w')%20as%20f%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20for%20line%20in%20newLines%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20f.write(line)%3B)

Alternate solution that handles multiple empty lines in succession, as well as empty lines at the start. This is 44 bytes, and will become my solution depending on how the pending clarifications turn out:

```
qN/{_L!e&{"# This is not pythonic!"\}&:L}%N*
```

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES6), 70

Test running the snippet below.

```js
f=p=>alert((r='# This is not pythonic!\n')+p.replace(/\n\n+/g,x=>x+r))

//// TEST CASES /////

t1=`print "Hello World!"

Print "Bye World!"`
f(t1)

t2=`from os.path import abspath

lines = []
with open(__file__, 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        lines.append(line)

if lines is not None:

    newLines = []
    hasReviewedBlock = False

    for line in lines:
        if len(line) > 1: # \n
            if hasReviewedBlock == False:
                newLines.append("# This is not pythonic!\n")
                hasReviewedBlock = True
        else:
            hasReviewedBlock = False

        newLines.append(line)
    with open("d:/test.py", 'w') as f:
        for line in newLines:
            f.write(line);`
f(t2)
```